# crash my app then running app by emulator (API 23 Android 6.0)

Tags: android

In my app user can upload image by camera or gallery.
app run in nox player(4.4.2) whithout error.
but if I run app by emulator android studio (Nexus 6 API 23 Android 6.0),app When upload image is crashed.
also app Catch permission for use camera and read, write storage from user.

Error in android monitor :

```
10-03 01:00:46.258 3549-3549/com.google.android.apps.photos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.google.android.apps.photos, PID: 3549


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.apps.photos.photoeditor.intents.EditActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No 'output' extra specified and can not save to specified inputUri: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F37/ACTUAL/1435618852
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No 'output' extra specified and can not save to specified inputUri: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F37/ACTUAL/1435618852
                                                                                      at com.google.android.apps.photos.photoeditor.intents.EditActivity.a(PG:11301)
                                                                                      at ggt.a(PG:87)
                                                                                      at lhy.a(PG:219)
                                                                                      at lhy.O_(PG:189)
                                                                                      at ngn.a(PG:188)
                                                                                      at ngk.a(PG:92)
                                                                                      at ngk.l(PG:184)
                                                                                      at nhi.onResume(PG:64)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6312)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

build.gradle code :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.mosayebtorabi.sapp"
            minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

Activity Code :

```
package ir.mosayebtorabi.sapp.Register_Pack;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Calendar;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
import ir.mosayebtorabi.sapp.Global_Class.Global;
import ir.mosayebtorabi.sapp.Global_Class.Request_Permissions;
import ir.mosayebtorabi.sapp.R;
import ir.mosayebtorabi.sapp.Register_Pack.Load_Last_Project.List_Of_Last_Project;
import ir.mosayebtorabi.sapp.Global_Class.Roozh;

public class Get_Info_New_Admin extends AppCompatActivity {

    Request_Permissions Request_Permissions;
    static Get_Info_New_Admin Get_Info_New_Admin;

    Add_New_ProjectControl Add_New_ProjectControl;
    Get_Last_CompanyCode Get_Last_CompanyCode;
    ir.mosayebtorabi.sapp.Register_Pack.Delete_Pic_From_Server Delete_Pic_From_Server;
    CircleImageView fab;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button buttonCamera, buttonGallery ;
    File file;
    Uri uri;
    Intent CamIntent, GalIntent, CropIntent ;
    public  static final int RequestPermissionCode  = 1 ;
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics ;
    int width, height;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ProgressBar prog1;
    Button uploadButton;
    //upload
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    final String uploadFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/Sapp/.Profile/";
    final String uploadFileName = Global.Send_telephone_TelePhone + ".jpg";
    String upLoadServerUri = null;
    String Picture1="";
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    //upload
    Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get__info__new__admin);

        Get_Info_New_Admin = this;

        final TextView name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        final TextView family=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.family);
        final TextView companyname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.companyname);
        final TextView projectname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.projectname);
        final Button send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        final Button back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
        fab=(CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        progressBar =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar33);
        prog1 =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.prog1);
        upLoadServerUri = "http://"+ Global.url_connection+"/Sapp/UploadToServer.php";



        File file2= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Sapp/.Profile/"+
                Global.Send_telephone_TelePhone + ".jpg");
        if(file2.exists())
        {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(file2));

            fab.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }else{
            if (!Global.C0_adapter_ProfilePic.equals("")) {
                Glide.with(Get_Info_New_Admin.this).load("http://"+ Global.url_connection+"/Sapp/profile_pic/" +
                        Global.C0_adapter_ProfilePic).into(fab);
            }else{
                Glide.with(Get_Info_New_Admin.this).load(R.drawable.blankimageforshoe).into(fab);
            }
        }






        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                selectImage();
            }
        });

if (!Global.C0_apiservis_Name.equals("")){
    name.setText(Global.C0_apiservis_Name);
    family.setText(Global.C0_apiservis_Family);
    name.setEnabled(false);
    family.setEnabled(false);

}

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent aaaaa=new Intent(Get_Info_New_Admin.this,List_Of_Last_Project.class);
                Get_Info_New_Admin.this.startActivity(aaaaa);
                ((Activity) Get_Info_New_Admin.this).finish();
            }
        });
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String list="";
                if (name.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    name.setError("نام خود را وارد کنید");
                    name.requestFocus();
                    list="notok";
                }
                if (family.getText().toString().equals("") && !list.equals("notok")){
                    family.setError("نام خانوادگی خود را وارد کنید");
                    family.requestFocus();
                    list="notok";
                }
                if (companyname.getText().toString().equals("") && !list.equals("notok")){
                    companyname.setError("نام شرکت را وارد کنید");
                    companyname.requestFocus();
                    list="notok";
                }
                if (projectname.getText().toString().equals("") && !list.equals("notok")){
                    projectname.setError("موضوع فعالیت شرکت را وارد کنید");
                    projectname.requestFocus();
                    list="notok";
                }
                if (!list.equals("notok")){

                    //get last companycode

                    name.setEnabled(false);
                    family.setEnabled(false);
                    companyname.setEnabled(false);
                    projectname.setEnabled(false);
                    prog1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    int CompanyCode11=Integer.parseInt(Global.Get_Last_CompanyCode_CompanyCode)+1;
                    String CompanyCode1=String.valueOf(CompanyCode11);
                    String companyname1=companyname.getText().toString();
                    String projectname1=projectname.getText().toString();
                    String Designation1="مسئول کنترل پروژه";
                    String name1=name.getText().toString();
                    String family1=family.getText().toString();
                    String TelePhone1=Global.Send_telephone_TelePhone;
                    String StatueUpLevel1="3";

                    Roozh jCal = new Roozh();
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int mo = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    mo++;
                    int da = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    jCal.GregorianToPersian(year, mo, da);
                    String Data_Accept1=jCal.toString();

                    String Staute1="3";
                    String Access1="3";
                    String Picture1=Global.Send_telephone_TelePhone+".jpg";
                    String Invited1=name.getText().toString() + " " + family.getText().toString();

                    Add_New_ProjectControl=new Add_New_ProjectControl(Get_Info_New_Admin.this);
                    Add_New_ProjectControl.Add_New_ProjectControl(CompanyCode1,companyname1,projectname1,Designation1,name1,family1
                            ,TelePhone1,StatueUpLevel1,Data_Accept1,Staute1,Access1,Picture1,Invited1,"online");

                }
            }
        });

    }
    public void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] options = { "دوربین", "انتخاب عکس از گالری","حذف عکس","انصراف" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Get_Info_New_Admin.this);
        builder.setTitle("انتخاب تصویر پروفایل");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("دوربین"))
                {
                    ClickImageFromCamera() ;

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("انتخاب عکس از گالری"))
                {

                    GetImageFromGallery();
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("حذف عکس")) {
                    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blankimageforshoe);
                    fab.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
                      Picture1="";
                    Global.Get_Info_New_Admin_SelectImage="";
                    //deleto from sdcard
                    File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Sapp/.Profile/"+
                            Global.Send_telephone_TelePhone + ".jpg");
                    if(file.exists())
                    {
                        file.delete();
                    }
                    //
                    ProgressBar progressBar33=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar33);
                    progressBar33.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Global.What_Page="Get_Info_New_Admin";
                    Delete_Pic_From_Server=new Delete_Pic_From_Server(Get_Info_New_Admin.this);
                    Delete_Pic_From_Server.Delete_Pic_From_Server( Global.Send_telephone_TelePhone,Global.Send_telephone_TelePhone + ".jpg");
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("انصراف")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
    //SAVE IMAGE
    private void save() {
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fab.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(getFilename());
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(Get_Info_New_Admin.this, "در حال بارگزاری", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                }
            }).start();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "خطای نامشخص", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    private String getFilename() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Sapp", ".Profile");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + Global.Send_telephone_TelePhone + ".jpg");
        return uriSting;
    }
    //SAVE IMAGE
    public void ClickImageFromCamera() {

        CamIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "file" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        CamIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        CamIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(CamIntent, 0);
    }
    public void GetImageFromGallery(){

        GalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(GalIntent, "Select Image From Gallery"), 2);
    }
    public void ImageCropFunction() {
        // Image Crop Code
        try {

            CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            CropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
            CropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 1600);
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 1600);
            CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 10);
            CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 10);
            CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
            CropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(CropIntent, 1);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                ImageCropFunction();
        }
        else if (requestCode == 2) {
            if (data != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
                    ImageCropFunction();
            }
        }

        else if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (data != null) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                try{
                    Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");
                    fab.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        save();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int RC, String per[], int[] PResult) {
        switch (RC) {
            case RequestPermissionCode:
                if (PResult.length > 0 && PResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(Get_Info_New_Admin.this,"Permission Granted, Now your application can access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Get_Info_New_Admin.this,"Permission Canceled, Now your application cannot access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
        String fileName = sourceFileUri;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize =30000 * 30000;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                    +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Get_Info_New_Admin.this, "خطای دستیابی به فابل", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }
                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
                if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(Get_Info_New_Admin.this, "آپلود فایل کامل شد.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                }
                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Get_Info_New_Admin.this, "اتصال برقرار نشد.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Get_Info_New_Admin.this, "خطا.مجددا امتحان کنید.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return serverResponseCode;
        } // End else block
    }
    public static Get_Info_New_Admin getInstance(){
        return   Get_Info_New_Admin;
    }
}
```

PHP Code (UploadToServer):

```
  <?php

        $file_path = "profile_pic/";

        $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {


            echo "success";
        } else{
            echo "fail";
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please show your code

Answer (score 0):

> No 'output' extra specified and can not save to specified inputUri

In your `EditActivity`, where you are using `URI` to save(or whatever), you didn't specify **the output path**, that's why you get the error.

For example, add a second paramater as the `output` path and then it will work.

Comment: but my app run in nox player(4.4.2) whithout error.

Comment: Seems like error came from `onResumed` condition. However, there are differences between emulators and real devices which you need to test the app in there. Anyways, just like I said in my answer, add a path and it will work after that.

Comment: Please add the related code to your question so that we can help you.

Comment: UploadToServer php :                                                                                          <?php
     
        $file_path = "profile_pic/";
        
        $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
   
    
            echo "success";
        } else{
            echo "fail";
        }
     ?>

Comment: What is EditActivity        ?